# Mapping multiple columns to a single key in a Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that looks as follows:

```
+------+-----+-----+
|acctId|vehId|count|
+------+-----+-----+
|     1|  666|    1|
|     1|  777|    3|
|     1|  888|    2|
|     1|  999|    3|
|     2|  777|    1|
|     2|  888|    3|
|     2|  999|    1|
|     3|  777|    4|
|     3|  888|    2|
+------+-----+-----+
```

I want to map each acctId's vehId to its count, and store that back in a dataframe, so the end result looks like this:

```
+------+---------------------------------------------+
|acctId| map                                         |
+------+---------------------------------------------+
|     1| Map(666 -> 1, 777 -> 3, 888 -> 2, 999 -> 3) |
|     2| Map(777 -> 1, 888 -> 3, 999 -> 1)           |
|     3| Map(777 -> 4, 888 -> 2)                     |
+------+---------------------------------------------+
```

What is the best way to go about this?

I have tried converting the dataframe to an RDD and performing a map on the rows, but I am unsure how to go about aggregating each map back to the singular acctId. I am new to Spark and dataframes in general but have done my best to try and find similar problems--apologies if this is a very common problem.

For your reference/use, here is how I am generating my test data:

```
val testData = Seq(
    (1, 999),
    (1, 999),
    (2, 999),
    (1, 888),
    (2, 888),
    (3, 888),
    (2, 888),
    (2, 888),
    (1, 888),
    (1, 777),
    (1, 666),
    (3, 888),
    (1, 777),
    (3, 777),
    (2, 777),
    (3, 777),
    (3, 777),
    (1, 999),
    (3, 777),
    (1, 777)
).toDF("acctId", "vehId")

val grouped = testData.groupBy("acctId", "vehId").count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use double `groupBy` for it as below

```
val testData = Seq(
  (1, 999),
  (1, 999),
  (2, 999),
  (1, 888),
  (2, 888),
  (3, 888),
  (2, 888),
  (2, 888),
  (1, 888),
  (1, 777),
  (1, 666),
  (3, 888),
  (1, 777),
  (3, 777),
  (2, 777),
  (3, 777),
  (3, 777),
  (1, 999),
  (3, 777),
  (1, 777)
).toDF("acctId", "vehId")

//udf to convert list to map
val listToMap = udf((input: Seq[Row]) => input.map(row => (row.getAs[Int](0), row.getAs[Long](1))).toMap)

val resultDF = testData.groupBy("acctId", "vehId")
  .agg(count("acctId").cast("long").as("count"))
  .groupBy("acctId")
  .agg(collect_list(struct("vehId", "count")) as ("map"))
  .withColumn("map", listToMap($"map"))
```

Output:

```
resultDF.show(false)
+------+----------------------------------------+
|acctId|map                                     |
+------+----------------------------------------+
|1     |[777 -> 3, 666 -> 1, 999 -> 3, 888 -> 2]|
|3     |[777 -> 4, 888 -> 2]                    |
|2     |[777 -> 1, 999 -> 1, 888 -> 3]          |
+------+----------------------------------------+
```

Schema:

```
resultDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- acctId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = false)
```

Comment: @Toy_Reid  I believe map is not thread safe here, so I don't think values in map column be consistent. Please make sure by verifying multiple times have exact data as expected

Comment: @Girish501 It would be better if you explain how a map is not thread safe here.

Comment: @Girish501 I would definitely appreciate if you could explain why that is! My testing has shown this to be accurate, but this will be operating on large datasets so having more info on how to test would be great.